# Investigating RDS MySQL 8.0.16 stalls on write-heavy workload

Tags: mysql, performance-tuning, mysql-8.0

I'm trying to track down some sporadic and difficult-to-reproduce issues with a MySQL 8.0.16 RDS instance connected to a web application with a write-heavy workload on a couple tables with large JSON columns. One table has ~3M rows, average row length is ~120kb, like 350GB of data total, almost all on the clustered index. The other has ~12M rows, average row length is ~20kb. The workload is like 80% INSERT and INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, with some SELECTs and DELETEs. We don't run any JOINs or complicated SELECTs that could be bogging everything else down.

The issue is:

For brief periods, like 1-20 seconds, once or twice every couple weeks, all INSERT, IODKU, and DELETE queries appear to be totally unresponsive. Write latency spikes, dirty pages spike, network transmit (but not receive) spikes, everything shows up in the slow query log, and then the issue resolves itself and everything returns to normal. We have a heavily seasonal traffic pattern and this issue first appeared on day 2 of our busy season. I'm hoping to track it down before the last week of the season which will have a few days of very high, sustained traffic.

I have pt-stalk watching production and caught maybe a smaller version of one of these when Threads_running spiked up to ~150 (usually it's less than 10). Of course, since it's RDS we don't have the diskstat/iostat/netstat output or anything, and the CloudWatch Metric intervals are too wide to tell me anything, but have a lot of information from `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` which I'm struggling to sift through. So far, the thing that stood out most was the File I/O part of the innodbstatus output during this Threads running spike:

```
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [27, 25, 21, 20] ,
 ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 1; buffer pool: 6251
138942220 OS file reads, 8230899625 OS file writes, 1653263701 OS fsyncs
5.60 reads/s, 16384 avg bytes/read, 1975.05 writes/s, 215.99 fsyncs/s
```

Most of the time we have 0 pending aio writes so that stood out to me.

Most of our innodb parameters are at default levels. I've tried bumping `innodb_log_file_size` to 10GB (since we write about 287 MB/min according to polling changes in Innodb_os_log_written and everybody says we should have an hour of redo) but that doesn't seem to have any effect when I run performance tests in a non-production environment. Production is still at the default for our version of MySQL (128MB).

Other important settings:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size 48318382080
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  1
innodb_flush_method O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_neighbors  0
innodb_io_capacity  200
innodb_io_capacity_max  2000
innodb_log_buffer_size  8388608
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  90.000000
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm  10.000000
```

RDS is specced out like so:

```
64 GB RAM
16 vCPU
4096 GiB General Purpose (SSD)
```

To try and come up with a concrete question:

1. Is it normal/expected to see pending aio writes like in that INNODB STATUS output?
2. We got up to like 8000 write IOPS according to CloudWatch when the incidents occurred -- does that mean innodb_io_capacity_max is too low at 2000?
3. Do RDS specs look appropriate?
4. What can I look at to pin this down further as either a configuration issue, a hardware issue with the RDS SSD, or a spec issue with the instance?

I appreciate your time and patience, as a humble application developer it's hard to know if I'm barking up the right tree or even in the right forest.

EDIT 1:

Adding show create for our largest table and obfuscated example of our most common query:

SHOW CREATE TABLE `A`:

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `z` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `x` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `y` varchar(255) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`z`,_utf8mb4'$.nested.other_id'))) VIRTUAL,
  `m` enum('about', '10', 'different', 'string', 'values') GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`z`,_utf8mb4'$.nested.enum'))) VIRTUAL,
  `n` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `y` (`y`),
  KEY `m` (`m`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31111111 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_c
```

```
INSERT INTO `A` \
  (`id`,`z`,`x`,`n`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES \
  ('12354678', \
   'a big json object, usually ~40-70kb, probably could be up to 250kb', \
   'a big json object almost identical to the previous column', \
   'a smaller json object', \
   '2020-12-02 18:30:13', \
   '2020-12-02 18:30:13') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE \
   `id`=VALUES(`id`), `z`=VALUES(`z`), `x`=VALUES(`x`), `n`=VALUES(`n`), `updatedAt`=VALUES(`updatedAt`)
```

Comment: Additional information request. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please pick up this data from your AWS RDS instance.  Do you have Skype TALK flexibility?  My Skype ID is wlhauck at aol dot com

Comment: Thanks for reading @WilsonHauck. Additional information is posted on this gist: https://gist.github.com/scitech/890c95e16d8103fedf1497fc2bbae21b

Comment: Thank you for data posted.  When can we schedule Skype Talk or chat?  Top of an hour for 15 minutes max.  My day is open. Could you post current results of SHOW WARNINGS; from production?

Comment: `SHOW WARNINGS;` has 0 results. I appreciate the offer to Skype but I would prefer to discuss here on StackExchange rather than on another platform if you don't mind.

Comment: To respect time required wth messaging vs talking, what we could review in 5 minutes with Skype TALK would take more than a day.  Your choice. 1st question, if you have 4TB SSD data space reserved, is there a reason you do not have 3 IOPS available for each GB of data storage to support your activity?  3 x 4096 = 12288 innodb_io_capacity and the system would double this to 24576 for innodb_io_capacity_max when the instance starts.  You are showing 200 for innodb_io_capacity and your system is BUSY.

Comment: This will likely require AWS Support ticket by you to get the question answered and assistance with raising the limit.

Comment: `SHOW WARNINGS` is valid only immediately after a command that has some warnings, and it applies only within the current session.

Comment: Rick, Thanks for the reminder. And Merry Christmas.

Comment: Re: innodb_io_capacity and innodb_io_capacity_max -- these are still the default values of 200/2000. No particular reason other than we didn't know whether they ought to be changed. After reading articles like https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/05/14/tuning-mysql-innodb-flushing-for-a-write-intensive-workload/ I am under the (possibly mistaken) impression that increasing these would only be useful if we want more background flushing of dirty pages. Is it still worth increasing these values if we don't have many dirty pages? (Though I suppose we could have spikes that aren't caught by monitors)

Comment: @trg - It seems odd to have the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column in an IODKU statement.  If you provide a value, then presumably you know it is there, hence `UPDATE` is warranted.  If you provide `NULL`, then it is equivalent to `INSERT`.  Or is there a secondary key that is `UNIQUE`?

Comment: I agree it's odd to be providing a value there, though there is a backstory: this column did not originally have AUTO_INCREMENT and was actually storing the AUTO_INCREMENT key from another table while we were transitioning data from that table to this one. That table has since been dropped and AUTO_INCREMENT turned on here. I should also point out that some of the time, the application is providing no value for that column (when a record is to be created), so the ORM will produce the same query but with `DEFAULT` as that column's value.

Answer (score 1):

Analysis of GLOBAL STATUS and VARIABLES:

**Observations:**

- Version: 8.0.16
- 64 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 188d 02:10:14
- You are not running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.

**The More Important Issues:**

Increase binlog_cache_size to 4M.

Increase innodb_log_file_size to 2G.

Increase innodb_io_capacity to 1000.  (Maybe more; I can't tell.)

Increase bulk_insert_buffer_size to 500M.

Increase host_cache_size to 1000.

Consider using DEACTIVATE PREPARE.

Turn OFF log_queries_not_using_indexes; it is mostly clutter.

Max_used_connections has reached 962; this may have lead to other problems.

If you are not using Replication and not saving the binlogs for anything else, consider turning log_bin OFF; this would save a bunch of I/O.

Unusually high number of CREATE/ALTER/DROP/PURGE EVENT/TRIGGER/FUNCTION/PROCEDURE/SAVEPOINT.  Though their frequency is probably significant, I question the schema design when such commands are used heavily.

I don't think this is valid:  `character_set_filesystem = utf8mb4`  It is normally "binary".  I worry that the "filessystem" may not allow such.  Were other charset things changed?

**Details and other observations:**

`( Key_reads + Key_writes + Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written + Innodb_dblwr_writes + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed ) = (0 + 0 + 138942227 + 2025439216 + 148032874 + 2025439206) / 16251014 = 266 /sec` -- IOPs?
-- If the hardware can handle it, set innodb_io_capacity (now 200) to about this value.

`( ( Key_reads + Key_writes + Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written + Innodb_dblwr_writes + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed ) / innodb_io_capacity / Uptime ) = ( 0 + 0 + 138942227 + 2025439216 + 148032874 + 2025439206 ) / 200 / 16251014 = 133.5%` -- This *may* be a metric indicating what innodb_io_capacity is set reasonably.
-- Increase innodb_io_capacity (now 200) if the hardware can handle it.

`( table_open_cache ) = 4,000` -- Number of table descriptors to cache
-- Several hundred is usually good.

`( Binlog_cache_disk_use / Binlog_cache_use ) = 222,113,817 / 451574927 = 49.2%` -- Spill to disk
-- Increase binlog_cache_size (now 32768)

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth * innodb_page_cleaners ) = 1,024 * 4 = 4,096` -- Amount of work for page cleaners every second.
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixable by lowering lru_scan_depth: Consider 1000 / innodb_page_cleaners (now 4). Also check for swapping.

`( innodb_page_cleaners / innodb_buffer_pool_instances ) = 4 / 8 = 0.5` -- innodb_page_cleaners
-- Recommend setting innodb_page_cleaners (now 4) to innodb_buffer_pool_instances (now 8)

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth ) = 1,024`
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixed by lowering lru_scan_depth

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed ) = 2,025,439,206 / 16251014 = 124 /sec` -- Writes (flushes)
-- Increase innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 48318382080)?

`( Innodb_os_log_written ) = 19,211,214,969,856 / 16251014 = 1182154 /sec` -- This is an indicator of how busy InnoDB is.
-- Very busy InnoDB.

`( Innodb_log_writes ) = 6,037,953,736 / 16251014 = 371 /sec`

`( Innodb_os_log_written / (Uptime / 3600) / innodb_log_files_in_group / innodb_log_file_size ) = 19,211,214,969,856 / (16251014 / 3600) / 2 / 128M = 15.9` -- Ratio
-- (see minutes)

`( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 16,251,014 / 60 * 128M / 19211214969856 = 1.89` -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, this can be changed dynamically; be sure to also change my.cnf.
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size (now 134217728). (Cannot change in AWS.)

`( Innodb_dblwr_writes ) = 148,032,874 / 16251014 = 9.1 /sec` -- "Doublewrite buffer" writes to disk. "Doublewrites" are a reliability feature. Some newer versions / configurations don't need them.
-- (Symptom of other issues)

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- I/O ops per second capable on disk . 100 for slow drives; 200 for spinning drives; 1000-2000 for SSDs; multiply by RAID factor.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( max_connections ) = 5,230` -- Maximum number of connections (threads). Impacts various allocations.
-- If max_connections (now 5230) is too high and various memory settings are high, you could run out of RAM.

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile (now ON) = ON is a potential security issue

`( bulk_insert_buffer_size ) = 8 / 65536M = 0.01%` -- Buffer for multi-row INSERTs and LOAD DATA
-- Too big could threaten RAM size. Too small could hinder such operations.

`( (Com_insert + Com_update + Com_delete + Com_replace) / Com_commit ) = (367369323 + 569825858 + 4993533 + 0) / 423300126 = 2.23` -- Statements per Commit (assuming all InnoDB)
-- Low: Might help to group queries together in transactions; High: long transactions strain various things.

`( Com_insert + Com_delete + Com_delete_multi + Com_replace + Com_update + Com_update_multi ) = (367369323 + 4993533 + 0 + 0 + 569825858 + 0) / 16251014 = 58 /sec` -- writes/sec
-- 50 writes/sec + log flushes will probably max out I/O write capacity of normal drives

`( ( Com_stmt_prepare - Com_stmt_close ) / ( Com_stmt_prepare + Com_stmt_close ) ) = ( 129325937 - 0 ) / ( 129325937 + 0 ) = 100.0%` -- Are you closing your prepared statements?
-- Add Closes.

`( Com_stmt_prepare - Com_stmt_close ) = 129,325,937 - 0 = 1.29e+8` -- How many prepared statements have not been closed.
-- CLOSE prepared statements

`( Com_stmt_close / Com_stmt_prepare ) = 0 / 129325937 = 0` -- Prepared statements should be Closed.
-- Check whether all Prepared statements are "Closed".

`( binlog_format ) = binlog_format = MIXED` -- STATEMENT/ROW/MIXED.
-- ROW is preferred by 5.7 (10.3)

`( expire_logs_days ) = 0` -- How soon to automatically purge binlog (after this many days). Being replaced by binlog_expire_logs_seconds.
-- Too large (or zero) = consumes disk space; too small = need to respond quickly to network/machine crash.
(Not relevant if log_bin (now ON) = OFF)

`( log_slow_slave_statements ) = log_slow_slave_statements = OFF` -- (5.6.11, 5.7.1) By default, replicated statements won't show up in the slowlog; this causes them to show.
-- It can be helpful in the slowlog to see writes that could be interfering with Replica reads.

`( log_queries_not_using_indexes ) = log_queries_not_using_indexes = ON` -- Whether to include such in slowlog.
-- This clutters the slowlog; turn it off so you can see the real slow queries. And decrease long_query_time (now 1) to catch most interesting queries.

`( Max_used_connections ) = 962` -- High-water mark for connections
-- Lots of inactive connections is OK; over 100 active connections is likely to be a problem. Max_used_connections (now 962) does not distinguish them; Threads_running (now 5) is instantaneous.

`( Max_used_connections / host_cache_size ) = 962 / 864 = 111.3%`
-- Increase host_cache_size (now 864)

**Abnormally small:**

```
Select_range = 0.02 /HR
Select_range / Com_select = 0.00%
gtid_executed_compression_period = 0.22 /HR
information_schema_stats_expiry = 60
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
Bytes_received = 1358576 /sec
Com_alter_event = 0.00022 /HR
Com_alter_user = 0.00066 /HR
Com_begin = 26 /sec
Com_create_function = 0.0049 /HR
Com_create_procedure = 0.0058 /HR
Com_create_trigger = 0.00066 /HR
Com_create_view = 0.044 /HR
Com_drop_function = 0.0049 /HR
Com_drop_procedure = 0.0058 /HR
Com_drop_trigger = 0.00022 /HR
Com_drop_view = 0.044 /HR
Com_flush = 13 /HR
Com_purge = 4.1 /HR
Com_purge_before_date = 7.9 /HR
Com_savepoint = 21 /sec
Com_show_engine_mutex = 0.0013 /HR
Com_stmt_execute = 58 /sec
Created_tmp_files = 0.35 /sec
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data = 2.94e+6
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total = 2.95e+6
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs = 6,252
Innodb_data_writes = 506 /sec
Innodb_data_written = 5779458 /sec
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs = 72 /sec
Innodb_os_log_written / (Uptime / 3600) / innodb_log_files_in_group = 2,029.3MB
Innodb_pages_created = 7.7 /sec
Ongoing_anonymous_transaction_count = 2
Prepared_stmt_count = 437
Ssl_accepts = 1.09e+7
Ssl_default_timeout = 7,200
Ssl_finished_accepts = 1.09e+7
Ssl_session_cache_misses = 1.09e+7
Ssl_session_cache_overflows = 106
Ssl_used_session_cache_entries = 127
Ssl_verify_depth = 1.84e+19
Ssl_verify_mode = 5
back_log / max_connections = 100.0%
host_cache_size = 864
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm = 10
innodb_undo_tablespaces = 2
max_error_count = 1,024
max_length_for_sort_data = 4,096
max_prepared_stmt_count = 1.05e+6
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
character_set_filesystem = utf8mb4
event_scheduler = ON
gtid_mode = OFF_PERMISSIVE
have_query_cache = NO
innodb_data_home_dir = /rdsdbdata/db/innodb
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
log_bin_trust_function_creators = ON
log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog = OFF
optimizer_trace = enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features = greedy_search=on, range_optimizer=on, dynamic_range=on, repeated_subselect=on
relay_log_recovery = ON
slave_exec_mode = IDEMPOTENT
slave_rows_search_algorithms = INDEX_SCAN,HASH_SCAN
time_zone = UTC
```

**From Comments**  Some comments on the Comments:

- "average row length is ~120kb" -- That is quite high, so I and not surprised that the default for the default `binlog_cache_size` was inadequate.
- There is not much I/O, so changing `innodb_io_capacity` may not make any difference.
- I don't know what constitutes a "bulk_insert_buffer_size", so I don't know.  The change is probably harmless, even if not helpful.
- "1.89 Minutes between InnoDB log rotations" -- extremely rapid.  Hence, the low value for `innodb_log_file_size` may be leading to the "stalls" you are experiencing.
- A "a burst of concurrent queries" would hit the logs and other things.
- `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is reasonable for the RAM size.  (You can't raise it much.)  I don't think you need to go to bigger VM.
- Why is it frequently "ramping up" and yielding a "cold" buffer_pool?  Such would hava a signifcant impact on latency (queries would run slower) and I/O (due to a lot of reads refilling the buffer_pool cache).
- Prepared statements (I think) come only from Stored routines.  Strange numbers like yours are something of a mystery to me; I am at a loss to give you specific advice, esspecially if you don't have any routines.  Perhaps the monitoring has some SPs?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. The binlog is enabled for the standby (this is a multi-AZ deployment in AWS's terminology), I didn't realize binlog writes were spilling to a temp file half the time, that's a good catch. Other charsets were changed when we upgraded from 5.7 to 8.0,  character_set_filesystem was probably changed unwittingly at that time. Will increasing innodb_io_capacity have a benefit even if dirty pages seem to be very low? Also will bulk_insert_buffer_size have a benefit if we don't do bulk inserts?

Comment: I'm curious what you think could be causing short stalls. My best theory is: we're overwriting the redo log and having to flush pages to make more redo room, does that seem plausible? Or is it impossible to tell without more information?

Could we just be doing so much IO that a burst of concurrent queries would cause enough contention to stall? Disk util looks low most of the time but our monitoring interval is pretty wide.

Could a too-small buffer pool be a possible culprit? The issues were more frequent when usage was ramping up so I'm wondering too if it could be a "cold" buffer pool?

Comment: I'm a little puzzled by the lack of closed prepared statements. Actually I'm not sure why there are prepared statements at all: our application interacts with this DB via an ORM, I thought it was doing simple INSERTs and INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATEs (though in a transaction), I'm not sure where the PREPARE is coming from. I'll have to look deeper into the ORM.

Comment: @trg - I appreciate your careful study of my analyses.  I responded to most of them at the end of my Answer.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Regarding my cold buffer pool comment, our application has a low amount of activity for most of the year, except for a 6-8 week period in the fall where the floodgates open and traffic is an order of magnitude higher. The beginning of this year's busy period was rockier for the DB than in years past - a handful of short but severe latency spikes. We've had occasional, smaller spikes since, but nothing like the first two days. I'm thinking the first week's issues could be buffer pool related, and the smaller, persistent issues may be related to the redo/bin logs.

Comment: @trg - Was I analyzing a "fall" time?  Also, a digest of the slowlog (in the "fall") could be helpful.  Sometimes knowing which queries are stuck in a spike/stall/slowdown can help root out the cause.

Comment: Yes @Rick James the information here is from the busy period, captured via `pt-stalk` at a time when Threads_running jumped to 133 and we saw one of the smaller latency spikes. I don't think we have the slow logs for this exact occurence, but all digests from similar incidents look about the same: 70% `INSERT UPDATE` on the largest table, 20% `INSERT` on the 2nd largest table, and a handful of other insert/update/deletes. Curiously, very few if any SELECTs ever appear in the slow log when we see these issues.

Comment: @trg - Let's see a sample of that IODKU and the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I've edited an example of the query and SHOW CREATE to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your RDS Parameter Groups - all dynamic

```
innodb_stats_auto_recalc=OFF  # to encourage consistent query completion
innodb_stats_persistent=OFF  # to encourage consistent query completion
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function every minute.
innodb_flush_neighbors=2  # from 0 to clear neighbors on the same extent in one pass
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=40  # from 25 percoent to accomodate 8 pages created per second.
```

This is just the beginning of needed Global Variable management to improve performance.
For additional suggestions, get in touch via Skype, please.